# Clothes clip and mesh deforms badly when rigging

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I've started learning Blender a couple of weeks back. I modeled a character and now I'm trying to animate it, but no matter much I've tried I just can't solve the rigging.

The issue is, it has quite a few clothes/accesories/pieces of armor (https://i.stack.imgur.com/irlMe.jpg), and I just can't get it to work properly.

The first issue is the clipping. Whenever I try posing, some objects clip through others (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqH4W.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIWpI.jpg). I tried adjusting the object's meshes/size/etc but it just works for one pose and then not for another, so that doesn't solve it.

The second issue is the mesh deforming quite horribly whenever I pose it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACxcq.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RD5g.jpg). While I'm sure a couple of this deformities could be solved by better weight painting, I just can't seem to do it no matter how much I try painting and repainting. I've been having this issue from the start but I figured my mesh was just too low poly, so I increased the polygons with subdivision surface and tinkered around with the topology to try and make it more posing friendly, and that made it better, but it's clearly not enough.

Final pic shows a mix of both problems (https://i.stack.imgur.com/koJr4.jpg) The belt has been a huge problem area. Lots of little parts and I can't get it to bend nicely either.

I'm putting a link to the blend file if you care to take a peek. https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oJY3WJzmqsTEs9u1CYPUkDpFUxJn6HT/view

I tried to solve it myself for way longer than I'd like to admit and I'm getting pretty desperate and frustrated at this point, so I hope someone can give me a hand. Thank you!

Comment: hello, please, instead of links, display your pictures in your message. What you cite are typical problems that you'll meet when rigging. Most of these problems can be fixed with weight painting, have you been through it?

Answer (score 0):

What you cite are typical problems that you'll meet when rigging. Most of these problems can be fixed through weight painting. For the top armor part (*Breastplate*), I've joined it to the rest of the body, then began to weight paint. Note that you have another top armor that is overlapping (*Breastplate.001*). Here is what it gives after a bit of weight painting:

[image]

Some clipping can't be avoided, in this case either mask the part that is supposed to be hidden with a *Mask* modifier, or play with shape keys. If a part is not supposed to stretch it should not be parented *With Automatic Weight* but directly to a bone.